# How to format a number as percentage without the percentage sign?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

How do I in .NET format a number as percentage without showing the percentage sign?

If I have the number `0.13` and use the format string `{0:P0}` the output is `13 %`.

However I would like to get `13` instead, *without* having to multiply the number by 100 and using the format string `{0:N0}`.

(Background: In ASP.NET I have a GridView with a BoundField where I would like to display a number as percentage but without the percentage sign (%). How do I do that?)

---

Thanks for the answers. At the time of editing 4 out of 6 suggest what I would like to avoid, as explained above. I was looking for a way to use a format string only, and avoid multiplying by 100 and using `{0:N0}`, but the answers indicate that's impossible...

---

Solved by using the accepted solution by [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67392/richard):

```
public class MyCulture : CultureInfo
{
    public MyCulture()
        : base(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)
    {
        this.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol = "";
    }
}

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new MyCulture();
```

Comment: What's wrong with multiplying by 100?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it; other than I would like to change the display of a number without changing the data query. In particular I would like to know how to display a number like e.g. 0.13 as 13 in a BoundField in ASP.NET - without the percentage sign.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Define a custom culture with its own [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo) which returns `String.Empty` for its [`PercentSymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentsymbol) property.

Then use that custom culture for impacted pages (or for the whole application). This could be done by cloning from the default so other regional settings are preserved.

Answer (score 15):

Why don't you just multiply the number by 100 and use your `"{0:N0}"` format string? That seems to me to be the easiest solution.

Unless you can come up with a viable reason why that's out of the question, that's my advice. It's not rocket science :-)

Comment: +1 It's either this or trim the %-sign after formatting it to {0:P0}

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean there is no way to scale the number in a format string? Maybe I should formulate another question like that.

Answer (score 5):

but multiplying by 100 is exactly what you want!

```
protected void myGrdiView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        myObjectType ot = (myObjectType)e.Row.DataItem;

        ot.myNumber = ot.myNumber * 100; // multiply by 100
    }
}
```

and in the HTML

```
<asp:BoundField DataType="myNumber" HeaderText="%" StringFormat="{0:N0}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN* has this under "Custom Numeric Format Strings":

> The presence of a '%' character in a
>   format string causes a number to be
>   multiplied by 100 before it is
>   formatted. The appropriate symbol is
>   inserted in the number itself at the
>   location where the '%' appears in the
>   format string. The percent character
>   used is dependent on the current
>   NumberFormatInfo class.

But the example shows that it also outputs the % sign - not what you want, but perhaps settable to nothing via the NumberFormatInfo class?

However, I agree with Pax and can't see why do don't go with the * 100 and {0:N0}

**Accessing from within Visual Studio so no link*

Answer (score 2):

How about this...

```
String.Format("{0:P0}",0.13).Replace("%","")
```

**EDIT:** This should work across cultures:

```
var percentSymbol = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PercentSymbol;
String.Format("{0:P0}",0.13).Replace(percentSymbol,"")
```

There is also [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932818/how-to-turn-off-percentage-sign-in-net-wpf) which may be more elegant but slightly more code.

Comment: Replace(" %"... - I thing that contains a space... or trim right the end result :)

Comment: This could fail in some situations, the % sign used is affected by culture.

Answer (score 0):

How about a trim?

```
double d = .102;
string percent = d.ToString("P0").Trim(' ', '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

A points to consider first, a percentage displayed without a % is a number so lets ignore the percentage aspect. You want to know how to display a number that's 1 or less as 100 or less. I appreciate that it's bound so you can't modify it at display time so why not modify it at query time, i.e. SELECT (value*100) AS Percentage, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like

```
string newString = "0.13".Replace("0.", string.Empty) + "%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using NumberFormatInfo as @Richard suggested:

```
string.Format(new NumberFormatInfo { PercentSymbol = string.Empty }, "{0:0%}", 0.123); // => 12
```

Comment: Can you add some explainations?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another shorter and cleaner way to do it.

```
$"{rate * 100:F2}"
```