# any way to hide percent sign in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Using .net 2.0 .

I want to display a column in a DataGridView as a percentage value, but without the percent sign.

example :

1) say data in data source is 0.1234

2) using a DataGridView column format string of "P2" makes the grid show this value as "12.34 %". What I want to see is : "12.34", i.e. the original value multiplied by 100, but without the percent sign.

I can work around this by using a calculated column with an expression to multiply by 100, but does the Grid provide an easier way ? Assume the grid is used in read-only mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939132/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-without-the-percentage-sign) for ways of doing this, though you'll see that the answer to your question is no, there is not a built-in way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ended up adding a calculated column instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the column format N2 instead.  You may need to multiply by 100 to get what you want however (as you've indicated)...