# how to turn off percentage sign in .net/wpf?

Tags: .net, formatting, internationalization

I would like my WPF application to display all percentages without % sign. For example 20% would be displayed as "20" but i still want to use the standard formatting for percentages (so i get the benefit of string formatter to multiply it by 100 for me)

in other words, how do i get
`string.Format("0.00%", 0.2)` to output "20" but not "20%"?

Is it possible to globally define PercentSymbol as empty string for the entire application?

In particular i am using ContentStringFormat in my WPF application to format the numbers and percentages. Maybe i can do it directly in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide your own `NumberFormatInfo` to `String.Format`. Example based on the invariant culture:

```
NumberFormatInfo info = (NumberFormatInfo) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
info.PercentSymbol = String.Empty;
string s = String.Format(info, "{0:00%}", 0.02);
```

Comment: Can i still use ContentStringFormat with a custom NumberFormatInfo?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

In theory the way you would do this is to create your own custom [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) for your application. Then you would create your own [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx). In this you can define the [PercentSymbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentsymbol.aspx).

Comment: How do set custom CultureInfo on wpf application?