# Find a format string for a decimal without % sign

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a number as percentage without the percentage sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939132/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-without-the-percentage-sign)

I have a decimal:

```
decimal value = 0.0123m;
```

The format string "P" will return a string which value is multiple with 100 and add sign % at the end. Example:

```
string s = value.ToString("P"); // s = "1.23 %"
```

Please help me to find a format string without including % sign on returned string.

> That mean: s will be "1.23" (without sign %)

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why not (value * 100m).ToString() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `PercentSymbol` property of the `NumberFormatInfo` to be something other than a % sign.

In your case you could just set it to be an empty string.

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString)

To do this you'll need to define a custom culture with its own `NumberFormatInfo`. The link to the answer provided in the comments in a great solution:

[How to format a number as percentage without the percentage sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939132/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-without-the-percentage-sign)